# Attaching Gazebo horizontal beams to the exterior wall

Tags: framing

I am planning to build 12X16 Gazebo with Gabel roof on my concrete patio that has been extended from the exterior house wall. I am using 6x6 for the 2 posts. I want to attach top horizonal beams (total 3, 2 from posts and 1 for the top ridge) to the exterior house wall. Exterior wall is having vinyl siding. Please advise how to anchor beams to the exterior wall safely and accurately.

[image: Patio]

Comment: Welcome to DiY! Some photos as well as a sketch of the situation would help. Also please include units (meters or feet) :)

Comment: You really do need more detail here. Is the roof open or covered? What material is behind the siding? Do you have good access behind? (Attic or finished living space?) Why did you choose to attach to the house versus freestanding?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Roof will be covered, I have no idea what is behind the wall as I haven't opened it yet, behind the wall I have living room and loft above it and yes I have access to attic.

Comment: I chose to attach it to wall because I do not want beams on inner side of Gazibo as the concrete patio is just 4 inch thick and it will look aesthetically better with out the beams on inner side where kichen countertop will be installed in the future

Answer (score 1):

We don't know enough about the actual house or design of the pergola to make a truly prescriptive recommendation. That would fall to a professional (preferably a licensed engineer) that's looking at your particular house (the structure available), the pergola structure, and the setting (snow/wind loads). I know we're all DIY here, but even as a working tradesman, I'd engage the services of an engineer to make sure the planning is done right and doesn't compromise the house or create an unsafe structure in the future. A PEng stamp on drawings also makes the permit process much more smooth.

(An aside on permits: some jurisdictions require a permit when you tie anything to the house structure. Even if yours doesn't, having permitted work improves the process/price if you sell the house in the future.)

So with that out of the way, the typical way to construct this is to put ledgers on the wall and attach the beams to the ledgers. You'll need to cut away the siding where the ledger is going and install flashing that keeps water moving to the exterior. Think of how water wants to travel: every time it drips, it should be pushed out and down.

[image: generic flashing detail]

The Simpson hangers, like a HUC66z, might possibly be specified for this use, but my concern (and again, where the PEng comes in) is that they might be insufficient to resist outward pull. Your engineer might specify tie-backs. In the absence of evidence to the contrary, I'm pretty sure Simpson doesn't list these hangers as appropriate for use directly into plywood or OSB or studs. Simpson-approved screws (more like lags, actually) may or may not be approved -- I'm not sure. Joist hanger nails are typical.

When it comes time to build this, rent a material lift to get your beams up in the air. Have more people than you think necessary to make the assembly smooth and safe.

The work for this project is apt to be extremely satisfying DIY. Given the downsides to failure, the planning isn't DIY.

Comment: Thank you @Aloysius. Really appreciate it. One thing I can see right off is that if simpson HUC66z made for a 6x6 then those mounting holes are likely about 7" apart so I may get lucky and hit one stud in the wall but very unlikely to hit a second stud 7' away and just securing to the plywood/OSB I'm sure will not be enough.

Comment: Those hangers are definitely not for mounting on studs.

Comment: Sure! That helps! Thank you!!